# Rails-generated query takes thousands of seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, database-performance

I see this query in `New Relic` as taking thousands of seconds:

```
SELECT "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."listing_id" = $1 ORDER BY "apps"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

It just destroys my performance. The table is bad, in that it has over 50 very sparsely-populated columns, and about 50 million rows.

`listing_id` is indexed. This is a `PostgreSQL` database and I literally do nothing other that allow it to be `auto vacuum`ed every day.

But I don't know where to look to make the query perform faster. This query is generated by `ActiveRecord`. It looks like it is probably just used to get the attributes of the table that are backup up my model. Is there a way to cache that so I don't have to have the query run?

Or is there something else I can do to make this "performant"? Please note that I've asked the same question a slightly different way over at the SE DBA site, so I don't need this question reclassified. My focus here is finding out why AR generates this query, and is there something I can do to alter it or make it more performant against such a bummer of a table.

Comment: What does Postgres's explain say about the query? Maybe an index on `listing_id` can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're looking for the smallest apps.id, and that isn't part of the index. So all matching rows must be read to get the id, and then sorted. I suspect that is what is taking time.

A compound index on `[listing_id, id]` should solve the issue.

Comment: The offending statement is: ```apps.first.standard```. At runtime, ```apps``` doesn't yet actually contain the data. Would that statement trigger the "limit 1"?

Comment: `.first` will cause `order by id ASC limit 1`. Which is quite fast assuming your table is indexed by id. I'm assuming `standard`is a scope that introduces the `.listing_id` part. At that point, the `id` index can't be used.

Comment: @AKWF I've added my suggested fix.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT "apps".* FROM "apps"
 WHERE "apps"."listing_id" = $1 ORDER BY "apps"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

in rails can be generated by a series of statements.

You can have

- `App.where(listing_id: X).first`
- `a_listing.apps.first`

so you could look for these two.